# style radio button with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to style all the radio buttons in the page with jquery (there is about 35 on this page alone that's why I want to use jQuery)

```
<fieldset>
<legend><b>Marital Status:</b></legend>
<div>
<div class="radio" id="box-single">
<input type="radio" id="single" name="marital_status" checked value="single">
</div>
<label for="single">Single</label>
</div>

<div>
<div class="radio" id="box-married">
<input type="radio" id="married" name="marital_status" value="married">
</div>
<label for="married">Married</label>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: So what is your question? Also, why jQuery and not in a CSS stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in this way.

**http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/**

Answer (score 0):

Apply literal CSS:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').css('float','right');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/K22e4/

Or, apply a class:

***CSS***:

```
.radio {
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

***JQuery***:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').addClass('radio');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/xjguG/